# How do I compleatly uninstall 'Unigine Benchmark Heaven 4.0' from Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS?

Tags: apt, uninstall, benchmarks

There are various associate directories on this system, but no entries in the Ubuntu Software App, Is uninstalling this package just a matter of deleting it's directories in the home folder? or are there other directories or apt dependencies that could go?

Comment: that depends on how you installed it So please add that to the question

Comment: if you installed it from the .run file from the website, check if there is an uninstall script included

Answer (score 1):

Go to the application installation directory and run `uninstall.sh` script. (c) - That is in manual. (The path was `~/Downloads/Unigine_Superposition-1.1` in my case.)

Comment: ...nice fix! thank you! You 

Comment: You could improve the post by adding a link to the manual.